# Physical Moon Earth Sun System

Tags: c++, orbital-mechanics

http://pastebin.com/ccck8LjE

Hello i've written this code to try and simulate the moon earth sun system. I get a circular orbit for the earth but the moon goes mad.

Is there a better way to try and do this whilst still using a euler/leapfrog method?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't take the effort to carefully review your code or test its behavior, but it is well known that the Euler method gains energy in such simulations, so "trapezoidal" is generally used instead.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule

If I understand correctly, your method is second order in the relationship between position and velocity (I assume with the intent of avoiding that energy gain) but it appears to be first order in the relationship between acceleration and velocity.

You might be able to keep the leapfrog design (rather than trapezoidal) but in trying to do so, you should do a better job of making the extra state explicit to eliminate the use of second derivative.

Edit: I reread the Wikipedia page on leapfrog and reread your code and it is clear you are not using leapfrog (as I said earlier because you only apply it to position\velocity not to velocity\acceleration).  Note that page also shows you how to simplify the equations of leapfrog for the situation (that you have) in which acceleration depends on position and not on velocity:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration

Comment: Okay cool, I'll read through that tomorrow, I'm very new to programming so I'm still getting to grips with how to do things.

Comment: I think it is more a math question than a programming question.  I think you correctly programmed what you understood to be the math of Leapfrog but had misunderstood the math. I expect that page will clear it up for you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try to use Runge Kutta methods if you want to keep using explicit integration : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods
RK4 is usually enough.